# CSS Triangle on materialui tooltip's right side

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, css-shapes

The problem is the content's height is changing on some tooltip
[this is how it is supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTyHT.png)
This is what i tried
[when content is small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfjx3.png)
[when content is big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP8oc.png)

this is the code of what i did

```
const ToolTip = withStyles(() => ({
  tooltip: {
    display: "inline-block",
    backgroundColor: "#ffff",
    color: "#000",
    maxWidth: 280,
    fontWeight: 600,
    fontSize: 12,
    marginRight: 80,
    boxShadow: "0px 60px 116px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0px 23.9688px 48.462px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0322996), 0px 10.925px 25.9101px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0260072), 0px 4.59406px 14.525px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0223691), 0px 1.44481px 7.71412px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.018802), 0px 0.13156px 3.21002px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0130265)",
    textAlign: "justify",
    paddingRight: 30,
    borderRadius:8,
    position: "relative",
    minHeight:"160px",
    border: "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
    '&::before': {
      content: '""',
      display:"block",
      position: "absolute",
      top:0,
      right:-80,
      borderBottom: "85px solid transparent",
      borderTop:"85px solid transparent",
      borderLeft: "85px solid #ffff"
    
    }
  },
}))(Tooltip);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use borders you could use `clip-path`. This lets you define a polygon in % terms so it will automatically adjust to the div's dimensions.

Here is a simple snippet to give the idea, the background is added through a before pseudo element which extends to the right beyond the width of the div which holds the actual text.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  width: 130%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-color: gray;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 70% 0, 100% 50%, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
  z-index: -1;  
}
```

```html
 <div>Some text here</div>
 <div>Masses of text here Masses of text here Masses of text here Masses of text here Masses of text here Masses of text here Masses of text here</div>
```